# Python Unit test a function imported by the function under test

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm attempting to implement thorough testing of code that calls to a database at various at points. I'm able to mock the calls that occur in the function under test, but I'm now also needing to stub out functions that are imported by the function under test.

As an example:

lambda_function:

```
from competiton.prizes import get_prize

def lambda_handler():
    # This has a call to DB and has been stubbed
    get_entries()
    some_functionality()
    get_prizes()

def get_prizes():
    return get_prizes()
```

competition.prizes.common:

```
from .db import get_from_db

def get_prizes()
    # This is the call I want to mock a return value
    some_info = get_from_db()
```

And my test:

```
class TestLambdaFunction:

    @patch("db.calls.get_from_db", return_value = (200, 100))
    @patch.object(lambda_function, "get_entries")
    def test_level_one_not_reached(self, mock_get_milestones, mock_get_reward):
        x = lambda_function()
```

While I am able to patch a function under test, such as the patch.object, the patch call above just doesn't seem to work and I can't figure it out.

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing. What is `lambda_function`, and why would you patch the thing (`fut`) you are actually trying to test?

Comment: You are (presumably) successful in controlling the value assigned to `some_info` in `get_info_from_db`. What else do you want or need to patch in order to control what `get_info()` does in order to test `fut`?

Comment: I'm trying to anonymise my code a bit. But effectively. I'm trying to stub a function that is imported by an imported function.

Comment: Which one? Your call to `patch.object` doesn't make any sense. You've already stubbed the most deeply nested call; stubbing anything higher seems to render that path moot (because `get_from_db` won't get called in the first place).

Comment: The stubbing of get_from_db doesn't work though. Stubbing of fut is to change one of the other calls to the db, which occurs in the fut (not stubbing get_info with that call).

Comment: As far as I can tell, `fut` *isn't* the function under test; `lambda_function` is. You don't have to post your real code, but you have to at least post a [mcve].

Comment: I have updated the example code a little to be a bit clearer on what's going on. I hope it's better.

Comment: Is `lambda_function` supposed to be the same thing as `lambda_handler`? Why is `get_prizes` nothing more than a `RecursionError` waiting to happen? Aside from that, it's `competition.prizes.common.get_from_db` you need to patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from .db import get_from_db

def get_prizes()
    # This is the call I want to mock a return value
    some_info = get_from_db()
```

`from .db import get_from_db` creates a new global name that's *initalized* using `db.calls.get_from_db`, and it's this new global name that `get_prizes` uses.

So that's the name you need to patch, *not* the original source from which `get_from_db` is initialized.

```
class TestLambdaFunction:

    @patch("competition.prizes.common.get_from_db", return_value = (200, 100))
    @patch.object(lambda_function, "get_entries")
    def test_level_one_not_reached(self, mock_get_milestones, mock_get_reward):
        x = lambda_function()
```

Comment: I see that's where I was falling over, I was not understanding that the new initialisation was changing the actual global name being used. Perfect, thank you.